# Jacob's blessing prophesy of Benjamin

Tags: prophecy

What are credible interpretations of Jacob's prophecy about Benjamin?

> Gen 49:27 “Benjamin is a ravenous wolf, in the morning devouring the
> prey and at evening dividing the spoil?”

Is there evidence of fulfillment in the biblical record of the Benjaminites, including King Saul, his son Jonathan, Saul of Tarsus, and the events of Judges 19:12-21:25?

Answer (score 1):

Note the remarks of some famous thinkers on the prophecy of Gen 49:27.

Ellicott:

> (27) Benjamin.—With this description of their ancestor agrees the
> character of his race, which was the most spirited and warlike of all
> the tribes of Israel.

Pulpit commentary

> Verse 27. - Benjamin shall ravin as a wolf (literally, a wolf, he
> shall tear in pieces): in the morning he shall devour the prey, and at
> night he shall divide the spoil. The prediction alludes to the warlike
> character of the tribe of Benjamin, which was manifested in Ehud the
> judge (Judges 3:15), and Saul the king of Israel (1 Samuel 11:6-11; 1
> Samuel 14:13, 15, 47, 48), who both sprang from Rachel's younger son.
> Genesis 49:27

Thus, Jacob's prophecy appears to have been fulfilled in the very aggressive and war-like character of the tribe of Benjamin.

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate fulfilment of that and previous eleven prophecies is Jesus Christ. You can study the words used in the prophecy and find them in the quoted below verses (https://biblehub.com/interlinear/genesis/49.htm).

*And Jacob called his sons, and said to them: Gather yourselves together that I may tell you the things that shall befall you in the last days.
...
Benjamin is a wolf; he tears his prey. In the morning he devours the prey, and in the evening he divides the spoil.* **Genesis 49**

Benjamin means the son of my right hand.

*Therefore I will give him the many as a portion, and he will receive the spoils of the mighty, because he willingly submitted to death, and was counted among the rebels; yet he bore the sin of many and interceded for the rebels.* **Isaiah 53:12**

*There the LORD will be our Mighty One. It will be like a place of broad rivers and streams. No galley with oars will ride them, no mighty ship will sail them. For the LORD is our judge, the LORD is our lawgiver, the LORD is our king; it is he who will save us. Your rigging hangs loose: The mast is not held secure, the sail is not spread. Then an abundance of spoils will be divided and even the lame will carry off plunder.*  **Isaiah 33:21-23**

*Come, let us return to the LORD. For He has torn us, and He will heal us; He has wounded us, and He will bind up our wounds.* **Hosea 6:1**

*Therefore, wait for me — this is the LORD’s declaration — until the day I rise up for plunder. For my decision is to gather nations, to assemble kingdoms, in order to pour out my indignation on them, all my burning anger; for the whole earth will be devoured by the fire of my jealousy.* **Zephaniah 3:8**